# Missing menus and other JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've been running/developing a site for several months but a couple of days ago the tables containing my JavaScript menus as well as an AWeber sign up box and my AdSense ad boxes all disappeared. When I look in Firebug, the tables are greyed out. I've checked for `display:none` but don't think it is being applied here. Firefox, Safari and Chrome seem to have this problem but Opera seems fine (for now, at least).

Being a new user I can't post an image of what I'm seeing in Firebug.

Does anyone have any idea why this has started happening, I'm completely stumped.

Site URL: www.templeofmysteries.com
Image link: http://www.templeofmysteries.com/images/error%20image.png

Comment: Without a link, all answers will be guesses. Can you provide one?

Comment: A diff of the relevant source files between now and a working version would be nice too.

Comment: When you get 10 reputation, you'll be able to post your image. Till then, just post a link to it.

Comment: of course how stupid of me: www.templeofmysteries.com

Comment: also the image can be seen at http://www.templeofmysteries.com/images/error%20image.png

Comment: Your image link gives an "The owner of this website (www.templeofmysteries.com) does not allow hotlinking to that resource"

Comment: Ok, apologies. I'm using cloudflare to try and speed up the site. I've now disabled hotlink protection and you should be able to see the image.

Answer (score 1):

There is an syntax-error:

```
missing ) in parenthetical
http://www.templeofmysteries.com/
Line 3
```

Insert an

```
)
```

before

```
(window,document)
```

I guess this error prevents all of your external scripts from being loaded.

Comment: Ah yes I think that is it. It's in code from a feature of Cloudflare called Rocket Script. I've disabled that feature because I don't have control of the code at that point (due to the way Cloudflare works) and now it all works fine. Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: @Paul Naples, if this answer solved the problem, then mark it as the answer by clicking the check-mark next to it.